# Is there a problem on using each boot manufactured on a different period?

Tags: boots

I bought a pair of Quechua Forclaz 500 boots from Decathlon 2 weeks ago, but just today I realized that each boot is manufatured 6 months apart (February and August 2012).

Is there a problem with that? They both seems very comfortable, and there is no sign of different aging on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit odd, I'm not sure what reason in production or otherwise would cause this to happen (perhaps a month or so, but 6 months seems weirdly long.) Perhaps a fault in one side of the boot caused a big reproduction, so the dates became out of sync - I can only speculate.

However, I see no reason for this to be a problem in practice - if the boots are stored well, which it seems like they have been, then practically there shouldn't be any difference between the two. If they seem fine and don't look odd in any other way, then I'd say there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: I think this happened in the store, and not in production. Decathlon here is a mess, so it is not far fetched to imagine they sometimes swap boots around. Anyway, I was a bit worried if the rubber, leather, fabrics, etc could show a difference.